# How to use parallelsAlwaysFailFast() in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

How to use parallelsAlwaysFailFast() in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline?
I could not find any example for this.

Edited, here is the code I use and the 'Blue Ocean' screenshot:

```
stage("Build") {
    parallel([
failFast: true,
        "Stage 1":{ 
            stage("Stage 1") { 
            stage("a1") { 
                println("a1")
            }; 
            stage("a2") { 
                println("a2")
            }
        }
        },
        "Stage 2":{ 
            stage("Stage 2") {
                stage("b1") { 
                    sh '''pwd''' 
                };
                stage("b2") { 
                    echo '''Here we can see the InterruptedException'''
                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                        error "Failing the stage"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
}
```

[Blue Ocean img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFa3G.png)

How can I make all the stages that are executed in parallel to fail as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) for the parallel step in scripted pipeline.

Comment: `failFast=true` seems to not failing all my parallel stages when one of them fails.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to change that behavior for all the future parallel stages.

However one can change it for any given set of parallel stages, like this:

```
def parallel_stages = [:].asSynchronized()

parallel_stages['one'] = {
    stage ('One') {
        script {
            println "One"
        }
    }
}

parallel_stages['two'] = {
    stage ('Two') {
        script {
            println "Two"
        }
    }
}

// Here you set this for the given parallel stage
parallel_stages.failFast = true

parallel parallel_stages
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to 'set this for the given parallel stage'?
I added a catchError with `buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'` in stage 'two' and an `error` in this catch.
Also added this:
`parallel_stages['one'].failFast = true
parallel_stages['two'].failFast = true`

I want stage 'one' also to fail like stage 'two' but it doesn't happen. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: `failFast` is a feature of `parallel` stages that instructs Jenkins what to do when one stage (out of several parallel stages) fails. If it's set to `true`, once one stage fails, all the others are stopped. If it's set to `false`,  once one stage fails, all the others continue to run (maybe they fail or maybe they succeed). In both cases, the whole `parallel` result is `FAILURE`. Seems like what you're trying to do is, not to fail the whole parallel process if one of the stages failed; if that's the case, `failFast` can't help you.